# C++ DLL (callable from VBA and receiving Range data)

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I am getting sick to figure out how to build a .dll to call in VBA and make possible my customized formulae. I want to make a .dll because of performance timing and so I started to study C++. As every project I've begun face issues after issues specially with the Range object to pass from VBA to my .dll.

Brief over my project:
with Visual Studio 2019 I built  a project with one file .cpp  and another .def to EXPORT my functions.

Everything went right when I have to pass from VBA simple double arguments, but when I should pass a Range of Cells, I started to face seriuos annoing problem which block my project.

Actually, I read too many forums and also section of Dalton's books to handle my issues, but anything it's really clear to me.

I found something which talks about COM and API C, other about "ExportImport.cpp", SAFEARRAY and VARIANT type (the latter: I could figure out how to pass arguments from VBA to C++ dll, but still don't understand how to achive and use single element and specially return them).

If it's not too annoing for some of you, I would like a specific description of what to do in this case. I am also new in Stack Overflow and don't know how to reward my saviour, but I would pay back in some way.

Thank you

Here my project which is called **square** and has two functions *square* and *my _array*:

**.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <OAIdl.h>


double __stdcall square(double& x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

VARIANT __stdcall my_array(VARIANT *p)
{
    //my statements and operation on the array (Range received from VBA)
}
```

**.def file**

```
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS 
square @1
my_array @2
```

Comment: What functionallity do want to code? Range parameter sounds like data, what is easier computed in a database.

Comment: I have to convert a code writtern in VBA to a c++ dll which has to do some operation. The VBA code already works well with my Workbook, but I would like to do a dll so it could performe better. I need to retrieve no just singular cells value (i.e. the inputs from the worksheets of my workbook), but also Range of Cells. The final goal would be to use the dll function in my workbook --> exemple (write the formula for square into a Cell): =square(A1)